# How to change view controller's title in storyboard

Tags: ios, swift

I have a ViewController, which is connected to a UINavigationController, that has two buttons, each one for a specific UITableViewController.

I drag and drop from each button to its corresponding UITableViewController and select show for the seque

the problem is that I can tap on the top of the first UITableViewController and set the name, but I can't do that on the second UITableViewController. my question is that normal?

please notice that the second UITableViewControlelr (Subtitle Cell Table View Controller) doesn't have a `come back` symbol like the other two do

[image]

as I am totally aware that I might need to wait because on swift still not a lot of programmers as in Android, i hope you help me

#### Updat3 1

I will add screenshot to show you my problem

this is the MainViewController

[image]

This is the first UITableViewController (as you see it has a title, which is players)

[image]

This is the second UITableViewController (**my problem is here** I couldn't add a title for it by clicking on the sense on my storyboard)

[image]

Comment: Let me try to solve it with you... Im Android and iOS Dev...

Comment: I need to know how you want to segue between the UITableViewControllers... The UINavigationViewController is to move inside a Stack, while your explanation seems to switch between both UITableViewControllers... Is that correct?

Comment: @Neo I have a MainViewController that has two buttons, each button should `show` a UITableViewController. I did that and when I click on each button the correct UITableViewcontrolelr appear with an option in the Navigation controller to go back to the MainViewController. However my problem is that in the second UITableViewController, when I tap on the header of the Navigation controller to add a title, nothing appear, i mean I can't write a title

Comment: In each UITableViewControllers viewDidLoad call title = "yourTitle"... Thats all

Comment: @Neo I already knew that, but my question was that I wanted to add it from the sense in my storyboard, the answer below solved my problem, I am just waiting for an explaining for why I didn't have to add this `Navigation Item` for the first UITableVewiController, and I had to add it for the second UITableViewController

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to drag a `UINavigationItem` into `UITableViewController`.

[image: Screenshot]

Navigation item belongs to a view controller and it is used to show the view controller title on the navigation bar. Every `UIViewController` has a Navitagtion item assigned to it. Its generated at runtime.

When a View Controller is pushed onto a Navigation Controller, the navigation controller gets the information for title view form the view controllers's Navigation Item.

So if you want to be able to change the title of a View Controller from storyboard, you need to add a Navigation Item in ViewController.

UINavigationController cannot have title changed, because, title belongs to ViewController, and navigation controller just show the relevant title onto its navigation bar.

Comment: how can that solve my problem please? I already dragged from one button to a UITableViewController and I didn't need this new `Navigation Item` and it worked, now in the second UITableViewController, my problem is that I can't write a title. However, I can completely come back and forth from the second UITableViewContoler to the MainViewControlelr and vis versa

Comment: how can that solve my problem please? I already dragged from one button to a UITableViewController and I didn't need this new `Navigation Item` and it worked, now in the second UITableViewController, my problem is that I can't write a title. However, I can completely come back and forth from the second UITableViewContoler to the MainViewControlelr and vis versa

Comment: how can that solve my problem please? I already dragged from one button to a UITableViewController and I didn't need this new `Navigation Item` and it worked, now in the second UITableViewController, my problem is that I can't write a title. However, I can completely come back and forth from the second UITableViewContoler to the MainViewControlelr and vis versa

Comment: If you don't add the navigation item in storyboard, its created at runtime, and assigned a title item. If you add this item in story board, it'll let you change its name, and it'll be associated to your view controller at runtime. Navigation Item is class, that holds view controller's title text, back button title text etc. *The back button title text appears in the next view controller's back button.*

Comment: @MarcoDinatsoli we two will solve this mate :-) Answer my comments so I can give you the right advice

Comment: @MarcoDinatsoli see my edited answer for explanation.

Comment: @AdilSoomro please see my updated questions. I am not asking about this navigation item at all

Comment: @AdilSoomro you were write from the first place, i am sorry, thank you very much

Comment: @AdilSoomro i read the description you added and that makes it clear. but i wonder why i didn't have to add that navigation item for the first UITableViewController, and I had to in the second UITableViewConstroller ?

Comment: It seems the view controller that's created by default in the storyboard through wizard contains it, secondly when you drag a navigation controller, it also drags a table view controller as well as its root view. May be the preset contained these items but the one that you dragged didn't.